# Rails API and Strong PARAMS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-api

I am trying to create an api to create record Foo using the [rails-api gem](https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api).

I initially ran the generator command to tell rails to create a controller for me and it created this:

```
def create
    @foo = Foo.new(foo_params)
    @foo.save
    respond_with(@foo)
end
```

And this (Strong params):

```
def foo_params
  params.require(:foo).permit(:bar)
end
```

This is pretty standard stuff and will work when using form_for to submit data to the create method.

In my case, I'm creating a stand-alone API web service that will only interact via external API calls. 
So the issue that I'm experiencing, is I don't know how to post the :bar param via API. I tried posting a :bar param, but this leads to a 'param is missing or the value is empty: foo' error. I understand why this is happening, but I have no idea how to get around this...

Is there a better way to do this or should I provide the api param in a different way?

PS. Currently my api POST call looks like this:

`http://localhost:3000/api/v1/foo.json?bar=test@mail.com`

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use the ?+argument at the end of the url for a POST HTTP request, it's only for a GET request.

You must use the data component of the HTTP call, that is not embedded in the URL

therefore, you cannot just make this from your browser address bar and must use curl or a great tool as Postman (free on the chrome App Store)
and in this data field, you can include the object you want to post (postman gives you a neat key value interface to do so)

let me know if you need more details on the curl function for command line calls, but I recommend that you use a nice tool as Postman, so useful if you're not used to these calls

EDIT : this is the URL to get Postman : https://www.getpostman.com

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer. I failed to mention, but I am using postman @Nicholas

Comment: Perfect then in postman , select the post method, input the url as http://localhost:3000/api/v1/foo.json , then click on the body tab. There input your object as key "foo.bar" and value as "test.mail.com" (I'm not 100% sure about the syntax of foo.bar but I'm on my phone, cannot test on my computer right now) . What is important to understand is that .require(:foo).permit(:bar) means you expect in data an object named foo with a property named bar, foo is not related to the url but to an object included in data